# Using Jquery to get the div id?

Tags: jquery

How can I get DIV id or DIV class using Jquery if the HTML is similar to:

```
<div class="first" id="first_id">
<div class="second">text sample</div>
<div class="third"><button type="submit" class="some_class" id="some_id" >send</button></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to get the class or ID of the div "first", with the click of the button?

I know that using this Jquery code I'll get the button ID, but can I get, with some changes in this code, alert message with the class (or id) od "first" DIV?

```
$("#some_id").click(function() {
var test=$(this).attr('id');
alert(test);
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.closest(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to crawl up to that parent, like this:

```
$("#some_id").click(function() {
  var test = $(this).closest('.first').attr('id');
  alert(test);
  return false;
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/RPYYd/).  This crawls up the parents until one matches the `.first` selector, then just grab that element's ID.

Comment: When I last crawled up to my parents I was two years old!